# Writing a (WAV) out to a file only speaks one word (last word)

Tags: java, file, audio

I used the WritetoFile() method, as my word array uses blockingPlay, however, when I play back the file thisisatest_pause.wav in my file system, it only plays the last word in the array, which is "test". The full phrase is "this is a test" with a parameter specified pause. Here is the code

```
public void play(int pause, String filename, String path) throws InterruptedException {
    // play the words in order
    for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
        myWordArray[i].blockingPlay();
        Thread.sleep(pause);
        try {
        myWordArray[i].writeToFile("C:\\Users\\Justin\\Desktop\\JavaMedia\\thisisatest_pause.wav\\");
        } catch (SoundException e){
        System.out.println("Error" +e);

      }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What type of of object is `myWordArray[i]`?

Answer (score -1):

Because every iteration through the loop writes to the ***same*** file name.

I don't know what type of object myWordArray[i] is, but my psychic powers tell me that the implementation of writeToFile overwrites the file if it already exists.

Comment: myWordArray[i] is a sound object

Comment: sigh.... what class, what package, etc?  It doesn't matter.  Your code is overwriting the same sound file on every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: myWordArray is a static sound array that reads splice points in a sound. I don't know how to write this to a file without it overwriting because of the for loop...

Comment: I think what you are really trying to say is, *"how do I concatenate all my sound objects into a single WAV file"* ?  I actually don't know.  Alternatively, you could save each sound to it's own unique file. Then use a 3rd party tool to do the final mix.